# How to highlight specific column value text in APEX Interactive Report

Tags: html, css, formatting, report, oracle-apex

From Oracle DB, I'm fetching records and displaying it in Interactive report. In that I want to highlight specific text.

For example,
"Here is the **Mango**" is the value retrieved from DB, I want to highlight the text "Mango" alone. I dont want to highlight the whole text.

The column value "Here is the " is same for all records. Only the next part needs to be highlighted/Formatted

Comment: Hi, did any of the below answers helped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it, is by doing conditional styling in your report. Below is emp table, where when the job title is `president`, the text is highlighted in bold.

[image]

I achieved this as follows:

1. Add condition html to your query:

   ```
   select EMPNO,
        ENAME,
        CASE WHEN UPPER(JOB) = 'PRESIDENT' THEN '<span>This is a <b>'||JOB||'</b></span>' ELSE JOB END JOB,
        MGR,
        HIREDATE,
        SAL,
        COMM,
        DEPTNO
   from EMP
   ```
2. If you are on APEX 5.1, then keep the column type as `Plain Text`, and set the option `Escape special characters` to `NO`. If you are on previous edition, specifically using the component view, then you can set the column type to `Standard Report Column`

Comment: It is much better to use HTML Expression property of the report column. 
If value of the column contains HTML than if will look good in the grid but it will break sorting and filtering features.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML Expression** is good approach in your case since "Here is the " text is same for all records and you want to highlight remaining part.

Enter this in your column formatting,

Here is the **#COLUMN_NAME#**

Screenshot

[image]